# How to fix the error: gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available?

Tags: lubuntu, gnupg

I am always getting the below gpg error message. I have also tried adding a PPA from webupd8 but the result is same. How can I resolve this error?

```
user@work:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.VlEePwgr6J/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available

user@work:~$ sudo apt-key adv -vv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410
[sudo] password for deda: 
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Z1cpSvPrvA/gpg.1.sh -vv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410
gpg: no running Dirmngr - starting '/usr/bin/dirmngr'
gpg: waiting for the dirmngr to come up ... (5s)
gpg: connection to the dirmngr established
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: Add the output of `sudo apt-key adv  -vv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410` to the question, please.

Comment: Did you change `/usr/bin/gpg`? Usually it doesn't start or require dirmngr, that's an indication that gpg2 is being used.

Comment: I did not change anything after the install yesterday. I just installed my lubuntu last night and when I will install spotify there is an error like that

Comment: This is happening on Debian too, freshly installed gpg. Definitely broken out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error trying to update to Mono 6. I solved it by switching from `keyserver.ubuntu.com` to `keys.gnupg.net` in the `apt-key` command.